# How do i escape mysql strings in C# for use with LIKE

Tags: mysql

I want to find a word in my list of tags. They can be at the beginning, end or middle so i tried writing.

```
Where name like "%@0%"
```

That didnt work so i tried

```
@"LIKE ""%" + MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(q) +@"%"
```

I thought that worked so i tried searching %. The results showed up all my tags, i expected only tags with % in them (so that would be none ATM).

How do i escape strings properly? and use it to search the middle of text?

-edit-

The solution is the below. I ran it against a few test and it passed them all. The query is

```
... where n.name LIKE CONCAT("%",  @some_name , "%") ...;
```

then in code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some_name", val.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("_", "\\_").Replace("%", "\\%")));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to escape `%` and `_` characters in the string, since those are special wildcards used by the `LIKE` operator:

```
@"LIKE ""%" +
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(q)
        .Replace("_", "\\_").Replace("%", "\\%") +
    @"%"
```

You might consider wrapping this in a static method for reusability.

Comment: I'll add that in but it feels like a hack. -edit- geeze, it doesnt even escape ". I cant use MySqlHelper.EscapeString at all. This isnt working

Comment: Try using a parametrized query.  Then your query text will be `... LIKE CONCAT("%", @likeParm, "%")`.  You will then only have to apply the two `Replace` methods to the string to make it ready to be passed in as `@likeParm`.

Comment: Hmm, close. ok this works with

`.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("_", "\\_").Replace("%", "\\%"))` -edit- i cant +1 cause i undid it 45mins ago

Comment: Make sure you quote quotation marks too or you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.  Using a parametrized query is really the best approach here.